# Where does qgis store calculated field from field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-3

When adding a (computed) field for a PostGIS table, where is the new field stored?

I thought it would be with the original table, but it does not seem to be the case for QGIS 3.0.1/3.0.2 (Ubuntu 16.0.4). When I create a calculated column `label` by copying from a column called `name`, the `label` column is displayed in QGIS but does not show in PostgreSQL (10.3) /PostGIS (2.4).

I was wondering where is the new column stored?

The content of table originally was:

```
=> select * from  tt;
 ogc_fid | name |                        geom                        
---------+------+----------------------------------------------------
       1 | i    | 0101000020416900000000000000000040000000000000F03F
       2 | i    | 01010000204169000000000000000000400000000000000040
(2 rows)
```

After the field calculation, *it stays the same* (without the new column).

The definition of the table as reported by `pg_dump` is:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 10.3 (Ubuntu 10.3-1.pgdg16.04+1)
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 10.3 (Ubuntu 10.3-1.pgdg16.04+1)

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: tt; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: db
--

CREATE TABLE public.tt (
    ogc_fid integer,
    name character varying(10),
    geom public.geometry(Point,26945)
);


ALTER TABLE public.tt OWNER TO db;

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: If QGIS would have added it to the data provider, the field would not be `virtual`. You can check that option when creating the field. On the other hand, QGIS is not able to self-update non-virtual fields containing computed values like `$area` etc.